# Why do I get an unexpected EntityManagerFactory when using JPA within WebLogic?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, jpa-2.0, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to create a Spring MVC web app (Spring Framework 3.0.5).  I am using IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 to deploy my app on a WebLogic Server (10.3.4).  One of my web pages attempts to store some data in a database using JPA.  My persistence.xml specifies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="LeaveSchedulerJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.engilitycorp.leavetracker.jpa.UserRole</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe "/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="leavescheduler"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However, when I look in the debugger, my EntityManagerFactory is shown as an `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl`, and when I call `createEntityManager`, I get an `org.apache.openjpa.persistenceArgumentException` that states that "A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property".

It appears to my newbie eye that the persistence.xml may not be getting processed.  I've tried putting it in `(project)/src/main/resources/META-INF` and `(project)/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring`, with the same unfortunate result.

I am not committed to using Hibernate persistence; however, I do want to use something that implements JPA 2, and I am having a real hard time configuring my environment.  For example, I have little idea how openjpa got involved in my app.  I suppose it may be the default JPA provider for something (WebLogic?, IntelliJ IDEA?).  Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

root-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
</beans>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.engilitycorp.leavetracker" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration files?

Comment: I just did.  Are there any others you'd like to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebLogic 10.3.4 is Java EE 5 compliant and is shipped with JPA 1.0 implementations: OpenJPA and TopLink.

According to WebLogic documentation ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#CIHDJHHI ) it can be used also with JPA 2.0 but only after applying a patch. Simply follow the instructions (patching seems to be quite simple but I didn't test it).

Probably you can also use your own JPA 2.0 provider without patching, as user1654209 wrote in first answer. But JPA 1.0 classes supplied with WebLogic can get in the way, because they are loaded by higher level classloader and have priority over classes packaged in your WAR file. To prevent such behaviour you have two options:

- pack your application's WAR within an EAR archive with `META-INF/weblogic-application.xml` file containing following lines (you must also include standard `META-INF/application.xml` file):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
  </weblogic-application>
  ```
- add `WEB-INF/weblogic.xml` file to your WAR archive with following lines:

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">

    <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
  </weblogic-web-app>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure an entityManagerFactory bean in your context.xml. Heres is an exemple using eclipselink as the JPA provider

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="jpaAdapter"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the provider isn't enough. You need to set the database connection data, like jdbc url, username and password. Did you set it? You also need to set the jdbc class name, as said, and the jdbc driver needs to be in your classpath.

If you are running this on a container and want to configure the datasource in weblogic, you can just refer to a jndi datasource from your hibernate cfg, but you will need to enter in the weblogic console and create a datasource and a connection pool there.

Look at hibernate docs on how to set the JNDI name in persistence.xml

Comment: I've added a more complete description of my configuration files.  As you can now see, the URL, etc. is set, and when I test the connection from IntelliJ IDEA, it connects okay, and I can view the database.